# Sort Number containing letters in numeric order

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a series of ID's that contain numbers but sometimes also letters. 
For example:

```
    1,
    A1,
    B1,
    A10,
    A11,
    2,
    A2,
    A20,
    B2,
    3,
    A3,
    B3,
    4,
    A4,
    B4
    5,
    A5
    B5
```

I need them sorted as following:

```
    A1,
    A2,
    A3,
    A4,
    A5,
    A10,
    A11,
    A20,
    B1,
    B2,
    B3,
    B4,
    B5,
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5
```

What would the best way to do this be?

The ID's are given to me externally and can't be changed.

Comment: If there is only 1 leading alpha character then this is fairly straightforward - if not then its not straightforward -  is your sample data representative - would you ever get zz1 for example and if so where would that fit into your required output

Comment: Maybe you should just redesign your table and make this two columns. Then sorting would be a no-brainer. (You could still have the concatenated ID as a computed column in your table.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question was originally tagged MySQL.

If the prefix is only one letter, you can do:

```
order by (id regexp '^[A-Z]') desc,                            -- put letters first
         (case when id regexp '^[A-Z]' then left(id, 1) end),  -- order by letter
         length(id) asc,
         id
```

In SQL Server, you would express this as:

```
order by (case when id like '[A-Z]%' then 1 else 2 end),
         (case when id like '[A-Z]%' then left(id, 1) end),
         length(id),
         id
```

Comment: Currently it only has one leading letter. Possibly more in the future but to be honest, seeing that is not the case i might be able to persuade the other involved parties to make it the rule.

Comment: Tried it, i just get a "Incorrect syntax near 'regexp'." error.

Comment: `regexp`? this is T-SQL, are you confusing with a different rdbms?

Comment: @ZoharPeled . . . The OP changed the tag.

Comment: @ZoharPeled i got my databases mixed up.